# Can a Dark Archon mind control a Hybrid?

Tags: starcraft-2

I've reached the point where I can allow my military access to Dark Archons, albeit at the cost of access to High Templar (I think). Now, High Templar are great units, but if I can turn the attacking Hybrid against my enemies, that could potentially open up the door for a huge amount of fun.

Is turnabout fair play? May I convince the Hybrid to destroy Amon's forces, much as he turned my Protoss against me?

If Mind Control doesn't work, does the secondary Confusion ability?

Comment: I am waiting to find this out myself - I'm a few levels away from unlocking perma-MC in co-op

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of Mind Control; unfortunately not. Dark Archon's Mind Control ability does not work on Heroic units, and all of the Hybrids are Heroic.

That said, the Confusion ability does seem to work, although it's a little hard to tell with large armies anyway.